# `dpkg -l` to only show installed packages?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

On Debian/Ubuntu, `dpkg` can show me packages, include the version and what's installed (e.g. `dpkg -l postgresql\*`). But that shows all packages that it knows about, whether installed or not.

Is it possible to make `dpkg` only show me the *installed* packages?

I've tried on dpkg v1.21.8 on Debian testing/bookworm, and v1.19.0.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Comment: According to the man page `dpkg -l` **does** only show installed packages (and packages with residual config). I can confirm this behaviour on my Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 machines.

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg` itself cannot do it, but it's possible to achieve it with a combination of `dpkg-query` and `awk`:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Status} ${Package}\n' 'linux-image-[0-9]*' | awk '$1 != "not-installed" {print}'
```

See this question over on Ask Ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330078/limit-output-of-dpkg-query-w-to-installed-packages

Answer (score 2):

1. `dpkg -l` command to list ALL installed Debian packages
2. `dpkg -l <pattern> | grep ^ii` command to show installed packages for `pattern`

For example, if you want to list installed packages for `gcc*`

```bash
$ dpkg -l gcc*|grep ^ii
ii  gcc                             4:12.2.0-1   amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-10                          10.4.0-5     amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-10-base:amd64               10.4.0-5     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-10-multilib                 10.4.0-5     amd64        GNU C compiler (multilib support)
ii  gcc-11                          11.3.0-5     amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-11-base:amd64               11.3.0-5     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-11-multilib                 11.3.0-5     amd64        GNU C compiler (multilib support)
ii  gcc-12                          12.2.0-3     amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-12-base:amd64               12.2.0-3     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-12-multilib                 12.2.0-3     amd64        GNU C compiler (multilib support)
ii  gcc-9-base:amd64                9.5.0-2+b1   amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-multilib                    4:12.2.0-1   amd64        GNU C compiler (multilib files)
```